# Windows API base64 encode/decod

Tags: c++, api, encoding, base64, decoding

I want to base64 a big file (500MB)

I use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32803844/c-base64-unicode-null-bytes) but it doesn't work for a large file

I test CryptStringToBinary but it doesn't work too

what should I do????

Comment: Compile your application as a 64-bit application.  Both that code and `CryptStringToBinary` probably requires 500MB memory to hold the final string.  That is more than likely not going to happen with a 32-bit app.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  It works, but my teacher doesn't  let us to change settings, we should do this with the default settings

Comment: Tell your teacher that you can't perform magic.  If you are to use those functions, and you have to generate 500MB+ strings, it isn't going to happen easily with a 32-bit application.  Even if you were to barely get by, you've used up a lot of memory that your app may crash somewhere else due to memory exhaustion.  The only thing to suggest is to find an implementation that writes the data to the disk while the base64 encode / decode is being generated, and not have it string based.

Comment: is it possible to read file with `ReadFile` function by chunk and then base64 the chunk, and read the second chunk....?

Comment: You could take the original code you linked to and change the destination to a file stream.  Then write the bytes to the file stream --- in other words, `pDst` needs to be changed.

Comment: I posted an answer on the encoding issue.  The code at the link only needed a small adjustment to write to a file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is clearly that there is not enough memory to store a 500 megabyte string in a 32-bit application.

The one solution is alluded to by the [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32803844/c-base64-unicode-null-bytes?noredirect=1&lq=1), which writes the data to a string.  Assuming that the code works correctly, it is not that hard to adjust it to write to a file stream.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>

static const wchar_t *Base64Digits = L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

int Base64Encode(const BYTE* pSrc, int nLenSrc, std::wostream& pDstStrm, int nLenDst)
{
    wchar_t pDst[4];
    int nLenOut = 0;

    while (nLenSrc > 0) {
        if (nLenDst < 4) return(0); 
        int len = 0;
        BYTE s1 = pSrc[len++];
        BYTE s2 = (nLenSrc > 1) ? pSrc[len++] : 0;
        BYTE s3 = (nLenSrc > 2) ? pSrc[len++] : 0;
        pSrc += len;
        nLenSrc -= len;

        //------------------ lookup the right digits for output
        pDst[0] = Base64Digits[(s1 >> 2) & 0x3F];
        pDst[1] = Base64Digits[(((s1 & 0x3) << 4) | ((s2 >> 4) & 0xF)) & 0x3F];
        pDst[2] = Base64Digits[(((s2 & 0xF) << 2) | ((s3 >> 6) & 0x3)) & 0x3F];
        pDst[3] = Base64Digits[s3 & 0x3F];

        //--------- end of input handling
        if (len < 3) {  // less than 24 src bits encoded, pad with '='
            pDst[3] = L'=';
            if (len == 1)
                pDst[2] = L'=';
        }

        nLenOut += 4;

        // write the data to a file
        pDstStrm.write(pDst,4);

        nLenDst -= 4;
    }

    if (nLenDst > 0) *pDst = 0;

    return (nLenOut);
}
```

The only changes done were to write the 4 bytes to a wide stream instead of appending the data to a string

Here is an example call:

```
int main()
{
    std::wofstream ofs(L"testfile.out");
    Base64Encode((BYTE*)"This is a test", strlen("This is a test"), ofs, 1000);
}
```

The above produces a file with the base64 string `VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q=`, which when decoded, produces `This is a test`.

Note that the parameter is `std::wostream`, which means any wide output stream class (such as `std::wostringstream`) will work also.

Comment: thanks, it works, but It isn't exactly what I want. - Is it posible to change pointer with `setfilepointer` and read the file from second chunk?

Comment: 32 bit allows addressing up to 2^32 bytes which is 4 GB, 500 MB is just 0.5 GB. Assuming that `wchar_t` is 2 Bytes that would make up to 1.5 GB.

Funnily enough, despite you saying that 500 MB is too much your solution still requires that 500 MB memory block, just not the additional 1 GB for the destination